# display result based on drop down list

Tags: php

I would like to display the result which I have selected based on the drop down list. This is my drop down list code which is retrieved from the finish_product under bom table (calculate.php)

```
<tr>
Select product:
<select class="itemTypes">
<?php
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row1['finish_product']; ?>">
<?php echo $row1['finish_product']; ?>
</option>
<?php } ?></select>
<br/><br/>
</tr>
```

For example, under the drop down list I selected 'Table', how do I display the result in doCalculate.php?

Right now I just hard code **Table** which is not feasible. Anyone to help me out?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by displaying the result?

Comment: Post it via a form to the page you want and manipulate the posted variable?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain properly what does it mean by displaying the result. Do you need to redirect the page on change event of the dropdown ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many ways which you could accomplish your goal. I would suggest using a [JavaSctipt "onchange" event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp), detect the selected option, and then update the DOM with its contents.